# count weekly considering deleted ones till date

Tags: mysql

```
ID  |Created_Date|  Modified_date|  Deleted(YN) 
1   |01-01-2014 |   NULL         |     0    
2   |01-03-2014 |   NULL         |     0    
3   |01-04-2014 |01-11-2014      |     1    
4   |01-05-2014 |01-12-2014      |     1    
5   |01-08-2014 |01-17-2014      |     1    
6   |01-09-2014 |   NULL         |     0   
7   |01-20-2014 |   NULL         |     0
```

I need a count weekly, considering the deleted ones upto that specific week. For example,
if `12-29-2013` - `01-04-2014` is considered as week 1 and `01-05-2014` - `01-11-2014` is considered as week 2, the output should be as below:

```
|Date       | count|
|12-29-2013 | 3
|01-04-2014 | 5 (this is because on 11th, there is a deleted record)
```

query written as below:

```
select date_add(created_date, interval(1-DAYOFWEEK(created_date)) DAY)
created_date, count(*) from table1 where 
(date_add(created_date, interval(7-DAYOFWEEK(created_date)) DAY) and deleted=0)
or (deleted = 1 and  modified_date > 
DATE_ADD(created_date, INTERVAL(7-DAYOFWEEK(created_date)) DAY)) 
group by week(created_date)
```

The problem is, it is not considering previous weeks deleted data and not giving total count - deleted count. Please help on the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WEEK()` function and your query will be something like

```
SELECT WEEK(created_date) as W, 
  COUNT(*) as All, 
  SUM(deleted*SIGN(WEEK(Modified_date)-W)) as Deleted, 
  All - Deleted as Real
FROM table1 
WHERE created_date>='2014-01-01'
GROUP BY W
ORDER BY W;
```

Also if you plan to use this query to get results for more than an year you'll have to use `YEARWEEK()` instead of `WEEK()`

Query is not tested, hope it will work w/o modifications

Update for comment 5:

```
SELECT WEEK(created,1) W, 
  COUNT(*) AllCount, 
  n.c
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT 
     WEEK(modified,1) m, 
     count(*) c 
  FROM table1 WHERE isdeleted=1 GROUP BY WEEK(modified,1)) n 
  ON WEEK(created,1)=n.m
WHERE created>='2014-01-01'
GROUP BY WEEK(created,1)
ORDER BY WEEK(created,1);
```

SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1470e6/29)

Comment: In week1, there are no deleted records. The record which has been deleted falls in Week2. Record 3, which is deleted on 01-11-2014 should show the count only in week2 as deleted and not under Week1. It should consider deleted=1 and modified_date should be greater than current week, to calculate the deleted count. Since, the record is not deleted in week1, it should give as active count in week1.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response, please look at above comment for the query posted.

Comment: Query slightly modified as below:                                                          select w1.w, w1.countall, w1.deleted, w1.countall-w1.deleted from
(SELECT WEEK(created_date) as W, 
  COUNT(*) as CountAll, 
  SUM(deleted*SIGN(WEEK(Modified_date)-WEEK(created_date))) as Deleted
FROM table1
WHERE created_date>='2014-01-01'
GROUP BY W
ORDER BY W) w1 . It is giving count 1 even in week1 under deletes, where as week1 has no deletes. The modified date of delete falls under week2. It should count this in week2, instead of week1 data.

Comment: The result should not consider record # 3 in Week1 deletes. Similarly record #4 and record #5 count in Week2 deletes. Record # 3 count should appear in Week2 deletes. Record #4 and #5 count should appear in Week3 deletes. depending on their modified dates.

Comment: I think, we are very close to the result and this query is much closer. 1st week is giving correct results (tried to delete/undelete), but subsequent weeks, it is not giving correct results. Week2, in this case, the delete count should show only 1, but it is showing 2. and Week3, it is not showing any count., where as it should show 2.

Comment: Experiment with Week function and its parameter. Info [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php)

Comment: awesome. This works well using modes along with week function. Please let me know, if the same query can have cumulative count for week  with (Allcount -deleted).

Comment: This particular function groups the data by weeks. If you want cumulative aggregates for interval use `created>=date1 and created<=date2` and remove `GROUP BY` condition. Same for the nested select - instead of `GROUP BY` you should put `AND modified>=date1 AND modified<=date2`

Comment: This is not giving weekly cumulative. I tried to modify the query with alternative solution, but it is getting complicated.

Comment: The query i have used is 409 characters long, so could not copy it. Please let me know, if we have alternatives to get weekly cummulative on the (allcount-deleted) field

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AllCount, n.c FROM table1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(*) c   FROM table1 WHERE isdeleted=1 AND modified >='2014-01-01' AND modified <='2014-01-31') n ON 1=1 WHERE created>='2014-01-01' AND created<='2014-01-31';`

Comment: No. This will give only one record with total. I would need week-wise. For example, in this case, on 2013-12-29, we have 3 creates, 1 delete. On 2014-01-05, we have 3 creates and 1 delete, on 2014-01-05, it should show 6 creates and 2 deletes, instead of 3 creates and 1 delete. Ideally on 2013-12-29 (Allcount-delete = 2) and on 2014-01-05 (allcount-delete)= 6-2 = 4. It should show two records in this case, one cumulative for week upto 2013-12-29 and cummulative for week upto 2014-01-05 and so on.

Comment: Finally achieved, but it is very long query, which i cannot post here. it is like doing self join on same query named as t1 and t2 and join on t1.date>t2.date and group by t1.date. If we can simplify further on this, please revert.

Comment: @Hristov This query has minor issue. I have created 7th record in our sample data with date '01-20-2014' and updated 5th record with modified_date '01-17-2014'. Now our query does not track this specific deleted record nor the week is listed, as it does not fall on the weeks listed. Ideally this week should be listed, if there are no created, created as 0, but modified counted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query edited to cover the modified ones/deleted ones which are not falling in created weeks. Please let me know, if this can be simplified more. If not, this seems one way to achieve.

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM(
SELECT date_add(created_date, interval(1-DAYOFWEEK(created_date)) DAY)   W,     
  count(*) AllCount, 
  n.c
FROM table1
left JOIN 
  (SELECT 
     WEEK(modified_date,1) m, 
     count(*) c 
  FROM table1 where deleted=1 GROUP BY WEEK(modified_date,1)) n 
  ON WEEK(created_date,1)=n.m
GROUP BY WEEK(created_date,1) 
UNION ALL
SELECT date_add(MODIFIED_date, interval(1-DAYOFWEEK(MODIFIED_date)) DAY)   W,   
  n.c as ALLCount,
  count(*) Deleted 
FROM table1
left JOIN 
  (SELECT 
     WEEK(CREATED_date,1) m, 
     count(*) c 
  FROM table1  GROUP BY WEEK(CREATED_date,1)) n 
  ON WEEK(MODIFIED_date,1)=n.m
WHERE DELETED=1
GROUP BY WEEK(MODIFIED_date,1) ) x
ORDER BY W
```